# Python: Passing function with arguments to a function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have two functions:

1. library function which I cannot change say `lib_func( func, param1)`
   i.e. `lib_func` takes a function `func` and some other parameter `param1` as arguments.
2. user defined function `user_func`.

For example:

```
x = 0
y = 0
def user_func():
    global x
    global y 
    return sqrt(x*y)
```

Now the problem is I want to pass x to `user_func` as argument not as globals while passing `user_func` to `lib_func`.

Comment: You can't modify user_func() too, right?

Comment: yes you can modify user_func

Comment: If you can modify user_func, what is the problem? Just stop using global variables!

Comment: @Hannes I guess you didn't get the question.

Comment: Apparently not. But you haven't explained why those globals are there and why they can't be removed if you have access to the function source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function is simply an object that can be called so defining a class with a `__call__` method is in principle equivalent to defining a function. At least in the context you are giving.

So:

```
def user_func(x, y, z):
    return anything_with(x, y, z)
```

is equivalent to:

```
class user_class(object):
    @staticmethod # staticmethod so that it can be called on the class
    def __call__(x, y, z):
        return anything_with(x, y, z)
```

as it stands this is just obfuscation. But the magic happens when you create an instance with predefined attributes and you only specifiy the variable arguments as parameters for the `call`:

```
class user_class(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __call__(self, y, z): # No x as parameter!
        return do_anything_with(self.x, y, z) # use the predefined x here
```

but you need to alter the way you call `lib_func` then:

```
x = 0
user_class_instance = user_class(0)
result = lib_func(user_class_instance, param1)
```

So it will repeat to call the instance with different `y` and `z` but `x` will be kept constant

---

Most of such `lib_func` functions however allow passing variable parameters (such that will be given to the `user_func`), for example  [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html):

```
curve_fit(user_func, x, y, [initial_guess_param1, param2, ...])
```

there `user_func` will be called by `curve_fit` internally (you don't have to do anything!) like:

```
user_func(x, initial_guess_param1, param2, ...)
# Then curve-fit modifies initial_guess_param1, param2, ... and calls it again
user_func(x, initial_guess_param1, param2, ...)
# and again modifies these and calls again
user_func(x, initial_guess_param1, param2, ...)
# ... until it finds a solution
```

there `x` and `y` are defined and not changed when calling `curve_fit` but `initial_guess_param1` will be changed while finding the optimal `curve_fit`
.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `user_func()` with another function

```
def parameterized_func(local_x):
    global x
    x = local_x
    return user_func()
```

And then pass the new `parameterized_func()` function to your `lib_func()`.
This is not very nice, and will obviously change the global `x` variable.
I would suggest looking into and see if you can't change the `user_func()` function instead.

Comment: But we still couldn't get rid of globals.

Comment: You can't really get rid of using globals unless you have permission/possibility to change `user_func()`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood task correctly, you'll need two things:

1. create new function to wrap `user_func` with `x, y` params
2. use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to get one more function with passed params

Here's example.

Module `user_module.py` where `user_func` defined:

```
x = 0
y = 0
def user_func():
   global x
   global y 
   print('user_func', x, y)
```

Module `main.py` where you need job done:

```
def lib_func(func, param1):
    print('lib_func', param1)
    func()


# Create user_func with params:
import user_module

def new_user_func(x, y):
    user_module.x = x
    user_module.y = y
    user_module.user_func()


# Use functools.partial to create user_func with ready params:
from functools import partial

f = partial(new_user_func, 1, 2)
lib_func(f, 'param1')

f = partial(new_user_func, 3, 4)
lib_func(f, 'param1')
```

Output for this example:

```
lib_func param1
user_func 1 2

lib_func param1
user_func 3 4
```

Comment: lib_func is going to call user_func repeatedly with new arguments.

Comment: @iota, just create new func with partial for each set of arguments. I updated answer to show it.

Answer (score -2):

try to wrap the `user_func` and return a new function for `lib_func`:

```
def wrapuserfunc(x):
    user_func.x = x
    return user_func

def user_func():
    if hasattr(user_func, 'x'):
        print user_func.x

lib_func(wrapuserfunc(1), param1)  # user_func.x = 1
# get x in user_func
print user_func.x  # x = 1
```

`wrapuserfunc(x)` works fine. 
Function is object in Python.